# extracting attachment content from Mail::Part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, actionmailer

I'm working on an after_filter callback in my ActionMailer-inheriting class that should grab the outgoing message and stores its attachments to AWS using the Paperclip gem. The trouble is that I can't figure out how to extract the file from the Mail::Part object in order to pass it to Paperclip.

I expected this would be dead simple, but a couple hours of searching haven't turned up anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that binaries can be represented as strings. So on the Mail::Part object, call #decoded (or #read), use the resulting string to create a temp file, and then assign that file to an object that uses Paperclip. Something like this:

```
Tempfile.open do |temp|
  temp.binmode
  temp << mail_part_obj.read
  temp.flush
  temp.rewind
  uses_pclip << temp
  uses_pclip.save
end
```